# How to receive message stanza without sending self presence?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, mongoose-im

I am using mongooseim with Android and  Ios application. I just want to receive message from the server from background without sending self presence to anyone because this task is done by system. But I can't receive message stanza until I send my presence to the mongooseIM.

Do I missing something or there is a way by which I can get quick update from MongooseIM server in the background without sending presence?

Comment: I have found 2 related XEP that can help - XEP-0018 (deprecated and also this is not working in Mongooseim, although do supported by it) and XEP-0126 (deprecated but this is working fine. This affect the Last Activity of the person because it do sends the <presence type="unavailable" />). Any suggesions?

Comment: Why do you need to skip sending the initial presence? In case you do not have users in the roster, it's not going to cause a presence broadcast. If you have some roster contacts, why shouldn't they be notified about you going online?

Anyway, it seems there's some code for presence-invisible - https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/blob/542b22b181eb427422945bb9ce023e101735b8d7/src/ejabberd_c2s.erl#L1383 - but it might've bitrotten. I'm not sure if it's possible at all.

Comment: Hi erszcz, nice to see you. I am connecting to the xmpp server from the background (like Mongooseim push given a silent push regarding the new message stanza available) for that I just want to get message stanza without becoming online until user explicitly open the android/ios app

Comment: Because there are chances that the user2 has sent a message to user1 and user2 is waiting for the online presence of user1 (already subscribed by both). In this case, if I have enable mongooseim push (with silent). I just want user2 client to get connected to the server from background without showing online presence and then receive the message.

Comment: I am also using XEP-0022 for message events and as soon as user1 receives the message in the background, his client sends the delivered message stanza reply to user1, without showing online presence.

Comment: @erszcz , how whatsapp able to update the message from background without being shown online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you all you want to do is sync the messages when you receive a Push Notification. MongooseIM can be configured to serve a simple HTTP API with which you can get archived messages (*mod_mam* needs to be enabled) without establishing the XMPP connection. More details can be found in the [HTTP API doc](https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-api/Client-frontend/), especially the Swagger doc regarding [get messages](https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/swagger/index.html?client=true#!/One-to-one_messages/get_messages). Let me know if this suites you.

Comment: Yes, this seems exactly what I want

Comment: Also, I am using mod_offline module. Will this HTTP API doc also work with that?

Comment: I'm glad this helps you :) Regarding the offline messages, no currently the HTTP API doesn't provide them.

Comment: Hi @michalwski, I have asked more elaborated question on https://stackoverflow.com/q/54630204/3102733. Although this question is more from the Android/Firebase point of view. Still I added Mongooseim tag because it is related

Comment: I just want to know the best approach for this new question